# How to set artifact path outside of Agent checkout folder in Teamcity?

Tags: docker, teamcity

I have two zip files that I want to be able to access with the TeamCity UI, but I have it zip outside the Build Agent checkout directory. My Build Agents are run inside containers.

Is there a way to select other directories/files outside like in the C:/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I just put in the path to the zip files I wanted to be accessible through the **Artifact Paths** field in the UI and it worked.

I was originally typing it in the artifact dependencies field, but I needed to type it into the Artifacts path field in **General Settings**